# how to increase value with button click on javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning javaScript. I have created a simple app, that when I click the button every time I want to increase the value.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  addCart();
});

function addCart() {
  let btnn = (document.querySelector(".cart span").textContent = 1);
}
```

```html
<ul class="cart">
  cart

  <span>(0)</span>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="click" class="btn" />
```

Comment: Here's how to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/yLer34x9/ (you're getting downvoted because stackoverflow is not really a newbie tutorial site; please learn more and do more research before posting)

Comment: Read the text, convert it to a number, add one, set the new text

Comment: I downvoted because the code is sloppy and I see little to no effort to debug obvious mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Add a count variable and increment it by one on every click:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
let count = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  addCart();
});

function addCart() {
  count++;
  document.querySelector(".cart span").textContent = `(${count})`;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cart">
  cart

  <span>(0)</span>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="click" class="btn" />
```